# Unable to create list of lists depending on loop inputs

Tags: python

I am trying to create a list of lists based on several inputs affected by several loops.

**First loop will be :** 
(Number of funds to be found on the array)

**Second loop will be :** 
Find the funds names (defined by first input) (column 0 of an array that is 1000 lines x 7 columns), if input is found on the column 0 of the array, then create a list of the rest of that line and so forth for all the inputs required.

so far this is what I did, but did not manage to record the individual lists found, it only returns the last one.

Can anybody help?

```
#load file
from csv import reader
archivo=open ('book5.csv')
leemos=reader(archivo)
matriz= list(leemos)

#input hnumber of funds to look for
n_fondos=int(input('NUMERO DE FONDOS: ?'))

#create the list based on the number of funds selected above
for a in range(n_fondos):
    fondos=[]
    new_list=[fondos for a in range (n_fondos)]
    while fondos==[]:
        n_corto=input(str('INTRODUZCA NOMBRE CORTO: ?'))
        for fila in matriz[1:]:
            valor=fila[0]
            valor2=fila[1:6]
            if valor==n_corto:
                fondos.append(valor2)

#print the new list with all the diferent funds found               
print(new_list)
```

> If I input 2 and type to funds to be found it return a list of 2 funds, but just the last one I introduced.

Comment: Could it be that you just want `fondos` to be declared `[]` before your most outer loop? I would answer that if I'd knew what fondos and new_list are each for..

Comment: thanks for your interest. i created fondos[] in order to be able to keep asking for an input in case the name introduced was not found in the list, and new_list was trying to aggreagete lists fila[1:6] in case the name introduced with the input was found. but it happens that just the last found name is printed (like the previous var is overwritten)